# How can I scale down the size of my table in LyX editor to avoid it going off the margins?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have a table that looks like this in the editor:

[image]

However, when I compile the pdf, it runs out of the page margins like this:

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this? I guess [this](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/CopyTablesFromSpreadsheets) link is useful but I can not make any progress since many of them ask me to install some package/extension in LyX which I don't know how to do. If you can keep your answer simple and enumerate the steps involved, I will be grateful.

Comment: This could be done using the `tabularx` package (`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|l|l|l|l|}`).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

To rescale the table or to allow line breaks in the table cells.

**Rescale the table.**
*You need the `xgraphics` package installed. It might be installed already, else you have to search how to install it. That's a separate issue.*

1. Among the menus, click `Document > Settings > LaTeX Premable` and write

   ```
    \usepackage{xgraphics}
   ```

the click `OK`.

[image]

2. Place you cursor on an empty line before your table and in menus click `Insert TeX Code` to insert a TeX code inset. In it, write

   ```
    \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
   ```

*You can replace 1 with 0.9 etc. for narrower table.*

3. Place you cursor on an empty line after your table, insert a Tex code box and in it write

   ```
    }
   ```

Steps 2 and 3 should produce something like

[image]

4. Compile, and your table will be scaled down, achieving something like

[image]

*Here, the table still breaks the margin due to it's indentation. I'llmleave you to play with that.*

**2) Allow lines breaks.**

If you do not want the font scaled down, you can set the width of the table cells, which allows line breaks.

1. In a table cell, right click and choose `More > Settings`.
2. Under `Column Settings` set `Width` to e.g. `70` and `Text Width %`.

Then you can play around with the width of the different columns to get something you like.